# (Securely) Rendering HTML content from one browser to the other

Tags: javascript, html, security, browser, render

I have the rendered HTML content (DOM) of a page from a client browser, and I'm looking to render that within another browser (Chrome/Firefox), through Javascript.

It seems that there could various security concerns with that and could lead to malicious content being loaded/executed on the target browser (even after basic "script" and "URL" filtering). Is there a way to load this on the target browser securely enough?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The markup is the markup, it's not going to render the same in Chrome as it does in IE because the browser renders whatever it gets from the server.  With a little work though, you should be able to get HTML to render near the same in all browsers though.

Comment: Thanks. What does that "little work" translate into?

Comment: Mostly a strong focus on valid markup and good use of the CSS box model.  Responsiveness is also something to consider.  https://www.google.com/search?q=write+cross+browser+compatible+html+css&oq=write+cross+browser+compatible+html+css&aqs=chrome..69i57.12718j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: revised the question to be more specific

Comment: What is the security issue that would not already exist on the primary browser's rendered HTML? If A has malware, then B would have malware.

Comment: well, A may not have it but somehow hacks the HTML content that is transmitted to B, leading to the malware being executed/loaded for B

Comment: Then that's a "man in the middle attack".

Comment: Browsers don’t usually communicate with other browsers, so I assume you have some kind of server-side component in between? Then parse the HTML there, and use a whitelist to only let through what you have defined as “safe”.

Comment: That is correct. The challenge is what do we term/classify as "safe"?, if I were to not compromise on the rendering on the other side?